# Adding git alias to .bash_profile not working

Tags: git, bash

I edited my $Home .bash_profile to include some git alias commands. I am rather new to this and I can't figure out what went wrong.

**.bash_profile**

```
alias gs='git status '
alias ga='git add '
alias gb='git branch '
alias gc='git commit'
alias gd='git diff'
alias go='git checkout '
alias gk='gitk --all&'
alias gx='gitx --all'

alias got='git '
alias get='git '

PS1="\u$ "
alias ll="ls -lahG"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && \
. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && \
. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && \
. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && \
. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && \
. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && \
. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

I can't seem to understand what I did wrong. Any ideas?

**[EDIT]** Just wanted to mention that the part that I added is from PS1 up. For example `alias ll = "ls -lahG"` works well. The ones above do not.

**[EDIT2]** I tried to user gs(){ git status "$*"; } instead but that didn't seem to do the trick.

**[EDIT3]** The problem was that I had to source ~/.profile. What I ended up doing is putting it in the ~/.bashrc file and source that file at Sputnick's recommendation.

Comment: do you restart the terminal or execute . ~/.bash_profile. I see no error at the first look.

Comment: What went wrong is that you used an alias.  Use functions instead.  eg: `gs(){ git status "$*"; }`

Comment: if you type `alias` into the prompt what the prompt returns?

Comment: @Burntime alias rvm-restart='rvm_reload_flag=1 source '\''/Users/MLP/.rvm/scripts/rvm'\''' Not sure what that means

Comment: @WilliamPursell I tried that but it didn't seem to do the trick. One of the allias that I have works fine though so I don't see why using alias would be a problem...

Comment: It means the aliases are not allocated. This should list all allocated aliases.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use `~/.bashrc` and **not** `~/.bash_profile` for aliases.

`~/.bashrc` is for interactive use, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles & http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashbehaviour

And most important thing, you should source the modified file with :

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
source ~/.bashrc
```